# Creating A PartialFunction

Tags: scala

I am an absolute Scala novice. This question is therefore very simplistic, and hopefully someone will understand what is being asked.

When experimenting, I have seen I can create a [PartialFunction](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/PartialFunction.html) instance with the following code:

```
val p : PartialFunction[Int, String] = {case x if x > 2 => s"x is ${x.toString}"}
```

**My question**: How is a concrete PartialFunction[Int, String] created from the function `{case x if x > 2 => s"x is ${x.toString}"}`?

**In particular**, how does this function provide **both** the..

- `isDefinedAt(x: Int): Boolean` method definition

..and the..

- `apply(v1: Int): String` method definition

..that a concrete PartialFunction[Int, String] must have?

Behind the scenes, is `{case x if x > 2 => s"x is ${x.toString}"}` being turned into?:

```
val p : PartialFunction[Int, String] = new PartialFunction[Int, String] {
  override def apply(v1: Int): String = {
    v1 match {
      case x if x > 2 => s"x is ${x.toString}"
    }
  }

  override def isDefinedAt(x: Int): Boolean = {
    x match {
      case x if x > 2 => true
      case _ => false
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please feel free to dig around scala api for more details: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/PartialFunction.html Hope that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The authoritative answer can be found in [the Scala language specification](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/08-pattern-matching.html#pattern-matching-anonymous-functions):

> **8.5 Pattern Matching Anonymous Functions**
>
> An anonymous function can be defined by a sequence of cases
>
> ```
> { case p1 => b1 … case pn => bn }
> ```
>
> which appear as an expression without a prior match. The expected type of such an expression must in part be defined. It must be either `scala.Functionk[S1,…,Sk, R]` for some k > 0, or `scala.PartialFunction[S1, R]`, where the argument type(s) `S1,…,Sk` must be fully determined, but the result type `R` may be undetermined.
>
> ...
>
> If the expected type is `scala.PartialFunction[S, R]`, the expression is taken to be equivalent to the following instance creation expression:
>
> ```
> new scala.PartialFunction[S, T] {
>   def apply(x: S): T = x match {
>     case p1 => b1 … case pn => bn
>   }
>   def isDefinedAt(x: S): Boolean = {
>     case p1 => true … case pn => true
>     case _ => false
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> Here, `x` is a fresh name and `T` is the weak least upper bound of the types of all `bi`. The final default case in the `isDefinedAt` method is omitted if one of the patterns `p1,…,pn` is already a variable or wildcard pattern.